# Hive: Getting duplicate records despite of using distinct

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I'm using hive: `Hive 1.2.1000.2.6.5.3033-1`. Trying to `SELECT` the `DISTINCT` data from the source table but getting `DUPLICATE`records.

Query on source table:

```
select stdnt_id,crsc_cd,brnch_cd,regexp_replace(grade,'\\[|\\]',"") as grd
from DB_SRC.ALL_STDNTS where course IN ('CRS1','CRS2','CRS3','CRS4')
and stdnt_id is not null and stdnt_id <> "" and brnch_cd is not null and brnch_cd <> "" 
and crsc_cd is not null and crsc_cd <> ""
and stdnt_id='650014881';
```

Source result:

```
------------------------------------------------
stdnt_id| crsc_cd| brnch_cd| grd
------------------------------------------------
650014881|  APT|    SPL|    AA|BC|CA|AC|BB|BD
650014881|  TTN|    BSC|    BA|CC|DD|CB|BA|DA
------------------------------------------------
```

When trying to `SELECT` the data using:

```
SELECT distinct
   stdntkey,
   crsc_cd,
   brnch_cd,
   split(grd,'[|]')[0]  as grd1,
   split(grd,'[|]')[1]  as grd2,
   split(grd,'[|]')[2]  as grd3,
   split(grd,'[|]')[3]  as grd4,
   split(grd,'[|]')[4]  as grd5,
   split(grd,'[|]')[5]  as grd6,
   split(grd,'[|]')[6]  as grd7
from
(
    select stdnt_id,crsc_cd,brnch_cd,regexp_replace(grade,'\\[|\\]',"") as grd
    from DB_DST.PG_STDNTS
    where course IN ('CRS1','CRS2','CRS3','CRS4')
    and stdnt_id is not null and stdnt_id <> "" 
    and crsc_cd is not null and crsc_cd <> "" and brnch_cd is not null and brnch_cd <> ""
) A
LATERAL VIEW explode(split(A.stdnt_id,'[,]')) stdnt_view as stdntkey
where stdntkey='650014881';
```

`DUPLICATE` records in the result:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
stdnt_id| crsc_cd| brnch_cd| grd1| grd2| grd3| grd14 grd5| grd6| grd7
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
650014881|  APT|    SPL|    AA|BC|CA|AC|BB|BD
650014881|  TTN|    BSC|    BA|CC|DD|CB|BA|DA
650014881|  APT|    SPL|    AA|AC|BD|BC|BB|CA
650014881|  TTN|    BSC|    BA|CB|DA|CC|BA|DD
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Expected result:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
stdnt_id| crsc_cd| brnch_cd| grd1| grd2| grd3| grd14 grd5| grd6| grd7
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
650014881|  APT|    SPL|    AA|BC|CA|AC|BB|BD
650014881|  TTN|    BSC|    BA|CC|DD|CB|BA|DA
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

There are duplicate records in the result. The order is changing for `grd1| grd2| grd3| grd14 grd5| grd6| grd7`. Not getting why the `ORDER`is changing?

Tried_1:

```
Used ORDER BY but no impact on the result
```

Tried_2:

`explode(split(A.stdnt_id,'[,]'))`. In the `DB_SRC.ALL_STDNTS` the `stdnt_id` comes in array. Here those are split.

Using `stdnt_id LIKE '%650014881%'` in the query fetch multiple records:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
stdnt_id| crsc_cd| brnch_cd| grd1| grd2| grd3| grd14 grd5| grd6| grd7
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
650014881|  APT|    SPL|    AA|BC|CA|AC|BB|BD
650014881|  TTN|    BSC|    BA|CC|DD|CB|BA|DA
650014881|  APT|    SPL|    AA|AC|BD|BC|BB|CA
650014881|  TTN|    BSC|    BA|CB|DA|CC|BA|DD
98765001488101|  RSC|    INT|    BC|CC|CA|BD|DB|DA
650014880051|  KKI|    INT|    CA|AD|AA|AB|BA|DA
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Why do you have `explode(split(A.stdnt_id,'[,]'))`?

Comment: If you run your first query with `stdnt_id LIKE '%650014881%' ` instead of `stdnt_id='650014881`, what do you get? *(I'd bet a chocolate-chip-cookie that you get at least four rows, two of which have `,` in the `stdnt_id` column, and the `grd` in a different order.)*

Comment: @MatBailie I've updated my question with the outcome of the suggestion you made.

Comment: Wait...  ***THEY'RE FROM DIFFERENT TABLES!?***  That's the cause, there is different data in each table.  The reason you get four records in the second query is that there are four matching records in that table.  `split()` isn't changing the order, there are records in your data with a different order.

Comment: @MatBailie Initially I thought the same too. But when checked the source table then there are only two records for the stdnt_id labelled them as '''Source result''' in the question. But when trying to split it out there are duplicate records in the output with the order being changed for '''grd'''.

Comment: You ***CAN NOT*** tell me that `DB_DST.PG_STDNTS` only contains two matching records on the grounds that you checked a similar one *(`DB_SRC.ALL_STDNTS`)* and only found two in there.  If you want to debug a query that uses `DB_DST.PG_STDNTS` then you need to actually check *That Exact Table*, not a "similar" one.

Answer (score 0):

This is your first query, paraphrased...

```
select ...
  from DB_SRC.ALL_STDNTS
 where ...
   and stdnt_id='650014881';
```

This is your second query paraphrased...

```
select ...
  from DB_SRC.PG_STDNTS
       LATERAL VIEW explode(split(A.stdnt_id,'[,]')) stdnt_view as stdntkey
 where ...
   and stdntkey='650014881';
```

There are two key differences.

1. They're from ***different tables***, which ***can*** contain different data.
2. One explodes a list, the other assumes it's already exploded

*(The 2nd point means that your second query will match rows with `123,650014881`, `650014881,456`, etc, etc)*

So, to debug why the second query doesn't do what you want, check the data in the underlying table that it refers to.  Not A Similar One, The One It ***Actually*** Uses.

Try this, and you'll see that it's nothing to do with `split()` and everything to do with what data is in your table.

```
SELECT distinct
   A.stdnt_id,  -- VISUALLY inspect what `stdnt_id` you're selecting, from BEFORE the eplode
   stdntkey,
   crsc_cd,
   brnch_cd,
   A.grd,       -- VISUALLY inspect what `grd` you're splitting, and you'll see the order DOESN'T change
   split(grd,'[|]')[0]  as grd1,
   split(grd,'[|]')[1]  as grd2,
   split(grd,'[|]')[2]  as grd3,
   split(grd,'[|]')[3]  as grd4,
   split(grd,'[|]')[4]  as grd5,
   split(grd,'[|]')[5]  as grd6,
   split(grd,'[|]')[6]  as grd7
from
(
    select stdnt_id,crsc_cd,brnch_cd,regexp_replace(grade,'\\[|\\]',"") as grd
    from DB_DST.PG_STDNTS
    where course IN ('CRS1','CRS2','CRS3','CRS4')
    and stdnt_id is not null and stdnt_id <> "" 
    and crsc_cd is not null and crsc_cd <> "" and brnch_cd is not null and brnch_cd <> ""
) A
LATERAL VIEW explode(split(A.stdnt_id,'[,]')) stdnt_view as stdntkey
where stdntkey='650014881';
```